# Variable auto-track: call a function when the variable is set to the same old value and call another function when the variable is set to a new value

Tags: c++, c++11, variables

I wonder what is the best way in C++ to auto-track a variable so we call a function when the variable is set to same old value and we call another function when the variable is set to a new value. For example,

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public: 
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    bool isActive = false;
    
    void IsActiveChanged();
    void IsActiveIsSetToOldValue();

    
};

A::A(){}
A::~A(){}

A::IsActiveChanged(){
    std::cout << " isActive has changed: isActive now =  " << isActive << "\n";
}

A::IsActiveIsSetToOldValue(){
    std::cout << " isActive has set to the same value: isActive now and before =  " << isActive << "\n";
}


int main(){
    A *obj = new A();
    obj->isActive = true;   // this would call A::IsActiveChanged()
    obj->isActive = true;   // this would call A::IsActiveIsSetToOldValue()
    obj->isActive = false; // this would call A::IsActiveChanged()

    delete obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The classical approach is to make the variable private and expose it via a getter and a setter. A fancier approach is to wrap it in a class with an overloaded `operator=`.

Comment: See the duplicate post. I think it addresses your question.

Comment: @cigien the accepted answer in the other post is based on Boost lib and has been answered 10 years ago so I was hoping to get another answer to this question here

Comment: Actually, the first answer only suggests Boost as an alternative. But if that question doesn't solve your problem, just edit your question to link to that and explain why it doesn't work for you.